# Lost passport with Schengen visa

Tags: visas, legal, customs-and-immigration, passports, schengen

My passport was stolen in Prague on my way to Vienna. I filed a police report and our embassy swiftly acted by giving me a temporary passport for my onward journey to Munich and Rome. Upon exit from Rome, the immigration ask for the Schengen visa, when I told him that I lost my passport, he did not ask for any document to support my claim, he just stamped my new passport with exit. I am not sure if on record, I am officially out of the Schengen area or not. I am scared that without the lost visa, it appears that I am still in the area and might reach the 90 day limit and will be denied when I re-apply as it would appear I broke the rule. What to do?

Comment: If you're denied, can't you then provide both the police report and the atemped-on-exit new passport to show that you left?

Comment: Thanks Kate, but I need to know ahead, because denial due to overstaying will take all my chance of getting another Schengen visa in the future. Anyway, I will contact the Greek consulate that issued me the visa. I hope it reflects in their system.

Answer (score 16):

Please do not panic on losing your passport with a valid Schengen visa. You can get everything back, albeit with some extra money spent, all of which is legal and above-board.

First and most important, please carry a copy (hard copy and soft copy) of the passport (1st and last pages) and also the visa page with you before you embark on your journey.
Second, as often as possible, please leave your passport in the safety of your hotel so that it is not lost.

However in the event it is lost, please do not panic. I am an Indian, and I lost my passport with a valid Schengen visa in Spain, and here is what I did.

All you have to do is to file a police complaint of the loss. They will give you a copy of the complaint (please ask for multiple copies – 2 to 3 copies) of the complaint.

Then I took the police complaint along with the hard copies of my lost passport and the Schengen visa copies to the Indian Embassy in Madrid (you can get the address on the website). The embassy people are really helpful. I filled the relevant forms and submitted the same along with the relevant charges to the counter at 10 AM, and the embassy had my passport ready by 4:30 PM in the evening of the same day! I also asked the embassy to write a note to the French consulate. (I got my Schengen visa from the French embassy in India, and I would recommend everyone applying for a Schengen visa to do it through them. They are fast and very responsive.)

Next armed with the new passport and a letter from the Indian consulate, I went to the French embassy and narrated my loss. They took the documents for verification at 1 PM (I was there at the consulate from 9 AM). A little later they gave me forms to fill out. The same form that I filled while applying for the Schengen visa) An hour later the officer came down to tell me that all my documents are in order and that I will be given my visa by 4:30 PM. I was asked to come to the embassy again at 3:30 PM so that they could take my photograph and complete the other information details, which I did, and also paid the relevant charges, and by 4:30 PM I was given a Schengen visa once again...enabling me to complete my holiday trip, albeit with a 2 day loss.

So please don't panic; just ensure you have all your documents in order.

Comment: Is the passport you got temporary passport to return to india?

Comment: I am presuming that you are talking about the "EMERGENCY CERTIFICATE" ..which is a WHITE PASSPORT (which is a one time travel document valid for only one journey to a destination in India) .. right?

Answer (score 2):

Contact your local embassy or consulate. They should have record of your lost passport and you can show them your exit stamp.