# Lost passport with Schengen visa but want to continue traveling

Tags: schengen, passports

I had a 90 days Schengen visa, but unluckily I lost my passport along with my Schengen visa in Berlin a month ago. I've been staying in Germany for the whole month. Now I've obtained a new passport from my own country's consulate. Can I use this new passport + police report + photo copy of my lost Schengen visa to go outside Germany and visit other Schengen countries? I didn't find any exact regulations for that, so can anyone help me out?

Comment: See also http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10590/lost-passport-with-schengen-visa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the Schengen Area, there are no border checks between countries. This is actually by law; a Schengen country can't introduce systematic passport checks at the border with another Schengen country even if they wanted to.

So you should have no trouble moving around within the Schengen area. If you choose to leave the Schengen area of course, you would likely need a new visa to get back in (the documentation you have might work to get you back in, but I wouldn't count on it). If an official such as a police officer asks you for your papers, then the documentation you have should be fine.

Comment: Not at the border but passport checks do exist. Sometimes as close as 100 meter from the border. Chances are slim that you will actually be checked, but the chances exist

Comment: The key word here is *systematic*. That's basically something member states promise to each other, not a guarantee or actionable right for you as an individual nor something that would make a difference if there is in fact a police check.

Comment: Here is the translated version from my location's foreigner office **when the Schengen visa is still valid, and the inspectors not
Have concerns,
he can travel. It is always a question of prima facie evidence of
Circumstances.**