# How long does it take to get a new Indian passport after being robbed in Spain?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, spain

My wife's handbag was stolen in Barcelona, near the cathedral when we sat in the bench around 9 pm. It's an Indian passport with Hungarian residence permit, 200 euros, all gone.

We filed an official complaint at a police station at Las Ramblas and that's about it. We were told to contact the Indian embassy first. We did contact the Indian embassy, but we were told to come to Madrid from Barcelona to apply for a duplicate passport. The Hungarian consulate in Barcelona gave us a letter stating she can enter Hungary from Spain (should be accepted by the airline, Wizz Air). She can't travel until she gets Indian passport.

Does anybody know how much time the Indian embassy takes to issue a duplicate passport?

Comment: [This answer](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/26895/50234) has a first hand account of how to get new indian passport in case you lose yours in Spain. It says it is possible to do so in a single day

Comment: @RedBaron We were told it should take minimum 7 days from indian embassy madrid. We dont know the exact time. ((

Comment: @RedBaron The answer you have pointed to is referring to "EMERGENCY CERTIFICATE" (aka WHITE PASSPORT which is a one time travel document back to India) and not a DUPLICATE PASSPORT. Passports are printed in India, so it will naturally be delayed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We got our duplicate passport from Indian Embassy in Madrid in **8 days**. They were extremely helpful.

We applied for duplicate passport and gave these documents. One little hassle was we had to come to madrid from barcelona to apply.

1. Forms for issue of duplicate passport.
2. Police report
3. Affidavit stating circumstances for loss of passport.
4. Flight ticket proving arrival in spain, Copy of lost passport or visas if any.
5. 113 euro fee.

Procedure: http://www.embassyindia.es/consular-services/passport-loss-by-tourist-businessman-general-visitor-to-spain

We also went to Hungarian consulate in Barcelona - they issued official letter stating that my wife lost her residence permit and she can enter Hungary until the validity of her residence permit. It took just 2 days for them to process.

I hope this helps other indians, who lost their passports and visas in Spain.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to share your experience, feel free to mark the answer as accepted. Or to add any additional details that may help someone else in the future, facing a similar situation.

Comment: Could you also add some details, e.g. what documents you were asked to present at the embassy? Thank you!