# Passport lost in Italy with valid France Schengen visa

Tags: schengen, passports, uk-residents, chinese-citizens, lost-documents

I am a Chinese international student studying in the UK. Last week my passport was stolen in Italy and I made a police report. This Monday I got a travel document from the Chinese consulate in Milan and successfully returned to the UK.

My lost passport has a valid France Schengen visa. I plan to go to Europe again in a month and unsure if it's still possible. I've been researching on the Internet and some answers suggest my Schengen visa is wasted cuz it's lost and I need to apply for a new one. Some suggest it might be recoverable if I go to the France embassy.

I've got to try, now I'm on my way to the France embassy. Please wish me luck and if you have any suggestions/information, please tell me. Thanks!

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Yes you will need to apply for a new visa.  You will probably get some degree of sympathetic consideration, but I don't think it's possible for them to bypass the normal application process nor to waive the visa fee.

Comment: Thanks. I just read someone getting reissued a visa by the France embassy. I guess I’ll have my try https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10590/lost-passport-with-schengen-visa

Comment: @phoog Thanks. I just read someone getting reissued a visa by the France embassy. I guess I’ll have my try https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10590/lost-passport-with-schengen-visa

Comment: It looks like it was a fresh application for a new visa ("The same form that I filled while applying for the Schengen visa") including the fee ("also paid the relevant charges").

Comment: @phoog Ah you are right. I assumed he was not applying for a new one because in my area you have to make an appointment in advance for the Schengen visa (sometimes it takes weeks). But now I see the words you quote, I understand. Thanks!