# Lost Schengen visa while still in Germany

Tags: germany, schengen-visas, lost-documents

I am from a country outside the EU, currently visiting on Schengen Visa. My passport and hence my visa sticker has been stolen. I can get a new passport through the embassy of my home country, but what should I do regarding the visa? Do I need to get a new one? How do I get a replacement if I need it? Who should I contact in Germany to ask about this?

I am already inside the EU and plan to complete my stay here, my visa was valid till September of this year.

---

**Additional details asked by comments:**

- I do have soft copies of my passport and the visa sticker from before my entry into the EU. I also have email receipts for my airline tickets.
- I plan to file a police report today. The theft happened in transit between EU countries and I contacted police there and they said I can return to Germany and file the report there.

Comment: Have you reported the loss of your passport to the German police? They will enter the loss of the passport into the Schengen Information System. I could find no information about how border guards would deal with the missing entry stamp.

Comment: In case this is not clear, the problem is not about the visa (the border guards can see that one was issued in the Visa Information System). Some form of **confirmation when you arrived** is what they will be asking about. Show them the police report of loss of the passport and anything that shows when you arrived (ticket, bill etc.). They only want to know if you overstayed.

Comment: Did you happen to keep a hard/soft copy of your passport and the visa? I always travel with a photocopy of my passport and a photo on my mobile of essential travel documents in case of such a scenario. Your travel insurance will probably cover lost and stolen passports - the cost of a replacement, any emergency travel documents, even new flights and additional accommodation if the loss results in you being unable to travel as planned

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lost passport with Schengen visa](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/10590/lost-passport-with-schengen-visa)

Answer (score 2):

Have you reported the loss of your passport to the German police?

They will enter the loss of the passport into the Schengen Information System.

I could find no information about how border guards would deal with the missing entry stamp.

In case this is not clear, the problem is not about the visa (the border guards can see that one was issued in the Visa Information System).

Some form of confirmation when you arrived is what they will be asking about.

Show them the police report of loss of the passport and anything that shows when you arrived (ticket, bill etc.). They only want to know if you overstayed.

---

[§ 13 Absatz 2 - Allgemeine Verwaltungsvorschrift zur Durchführung des Passgesetzes (Passverwaltungsvorschrift - PassVwV)](https://www.verwaltungsvorschriften-im-internet.de/bsvwvbund_16122019_DGI220105713.htm)

> Die Passbehörde unterrichtet unverzüglich die örtlich zuständige Polizeidienststelle über jeden Verlust des Passes oder Passersatzes, damit eine Speicherung im INPOL-Fahndungssystem und im **Schengener Informationssystem (SIS)** vorgenommen werden kann.
>
> > The passport authority immediately informs the locally responsible police station of any loss of the passport or passport replacement so that it can be stored in the INPOL search system and in the **Schengen Information System (SIS)**.

Comment: "Some form of confirmation when you arrived is what they will be asking about." Hotel booking and a confirmation from the flight you boarded TO Europe should satisfy them of your entry date.

Comment: @Ozzy I doubt a "booking" would prove presence, as a booking is only a reservation. The hotel's _receipt_ for actually staying there (with dates) would be better.